# How to load my test data in C#?

Tags: c#, nunit, testing

I am struggling to find an easy way to load my test data in C#.

In Java, I load a resource using the following code:

```
...

public static InputStream loadResource(String resource) throws LoadException {
    InputStream is = TestUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);

    if (is == null) {
        throw new LoadException("Error loading '" + resource + "'");
    }

    return is;
}

...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream is = TestUtils.loadResource("/resourcelocation");
}
```

I tried to use C# resource file, but I found awkward to load and manipulate it. Is there a simpler way to load resources in C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes - use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx), e.g.

```
typeof(TestClass).Assembly
                 .GetManifestResourceStream("test.namespace.Filename.txt")
```

Just make sure the files are tagged as "Embedded Resource" in the properties, so they get built into the assembly correctly.

Comment: @David Reis If, like i did, you put your test data files in a folder inside of your test class library, then the directory will be part of the string. Fr example if the namespace is test.namespace and you put somefile.txt in someDirectory then the string is "test.namespace.someDirectory.somefile.txt" . A helpful method to use in case you cannot figure out the string is [this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)