# Relative path on unit test project c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs

I have a solution which has a console application and unit test.

```
var target = new Validator();
var targetFile = @"C:\Folder\SubFolder\AnotherSubFolder\Development\DEV\src\UnitTest\TargetFolder\file.xml";

bool actual = target.Validate(targetFile);
Assert.AreEqual(true, actual);
```

The Validator is located at the console application project, while my file.xml is located at the folder inside the unit test project.

This unit test is passing, however i want to make sure that when i check in this in to my tfs or build server, it can still locate my targetFile.

How am I gonna change the path of the targetFile?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?

Answer (score 12):

If I understood your issue correctly, it is not good that product code(in console application) depends on an item in the test project, so I recommend you to move `file.xml` to the product code project.

To solve your path problem, I think the best approach is to use the *Copy to Output Directory* property as *Copy always* or *Copy if newer*, which you can find in the VS Properties window.

Check out the following steps.

1. Make a folder if needed to put in `file.xml` in the product project(eg. Data folder).
2. Put `file.xml` in the folder.
3. Go to the VS Properties window for `file.xml`.
4. Set *Build Action* to *None* and *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy always* or *Copy if newer*.
5. Build and do unit testing as

   ```
   Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(@"Data\file.xml"));
   ```

   In this case, VS will automatically make the data folder with `file.xml` under output folder of test poject.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing right now. However, i don't know how to change the path of target file to be a relative path so that I can make sure that it will not have any problem on the build server.

Comment: I think that the important thing is to catch the current location in test project. Normally, the correct position is same with output folder(bin\debug) of test project. According to test framework, the output folder may be copied somewhere else, which is called shadow copy. However, in this case there is no problem because relative path is not broken.

Comment: Thanks. It really helped for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can reference the folder like below.

```
"..\..\TargetFolder\file.xml"
```

Comment: live unit testing doesn't have the same relative path than standard ms test

Answer (score 4):

I found out the solution to my problem. I used this:

```
"..\..\..\TestFileFolder\myFile.xml"
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is MS Unit Test is to use a `[DeploymentItem]` in the test of the unit test class.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute(v=vs.100).aspx for more details.  Also [How can I use a data file in a VS 2008 unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069429/how-can-i-use-a-data-file-in-a-vs-2008-unit-test)

Answer (score 0):

The location of `Validator` should not be relevant. Any relative path should be relative to the directory your test application is executing in, so just set `targetFile` to be a relative path from there.
Then make sure you are running your tests from the same relative location on the bulid server as on your dev machine.

Bonus tip: use `Assert.IsTrue(actual);`